# How to check if string is a valid sha256 hash in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, sha, sha256

How do I manage to identify a sha256 hash using PHP?
Also, is there any way to identify if the string is a sha256 hash even if it was salted?

I don't need to know the real value of the hash (I know that is impossible), but I need only to validate the string, so I can work in a way if the string is a sha256 hash and work another way if it isn't.

Comment: Why do you need that? Your questions leads me to believe that your idea of hashes is quite wrong.

Comment: I have a system that has two type of passwords stored in its Database. Since the system is very old, it used -nothing- to encrypt the passwords, storing then as plain text (pretty bad, I know). Some years ago, another programmer managed to change the security of passwords into SHA256 + SALT, but not every password is hashed. So, I need to identify if a password is SHA256 hash or not. Then, if it isn't a valid hash, i will do the job.

Comment: The only method of doing so is to check the size of the hash and if it doesn't have the same size of all the other passwords it needs to be hashed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to check if a hash is a valid SHA-256 hash is to check 256 bits in it- if it does, then yes some input CAN possibly generate that output.

Hashes are one way meaning I can give you a hash and you can never decrypt it (this is the difference between hashing and an encryption). This is good for storing passwords and such where the plain text value is irrelevant.

Answer (score 11):

I do not understand what you mean when you say: "even if it was salted". Salting happens before hashing, it offers some protection against rainbow table attacks and users using the same password on multiple sites. Depending on the base a simple regex can tell you if a particular string is a sha256 hash. i think most times we encounter hashes in base16, in that case this would work:

```
   if (preg_match("/^([a-f0-9]{64})$/", $hash) == 1) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but that's a question from 5 years ago :) - The idea was to migrate users from one hashing algorithm to another without compromising the user experience, by logging everyone out for example, and, instead, do it on demand. Five years later I see that there are numerous ways to solve this problem haha

Comment: I got here searching for way to validate if a string was really sha256. since others might have the same question i added an answer. :)

Comment: and 2 years later it is still useful!